# Does SslHandler's handshake go through all client/server pipeline handlers?

Tags: ssl, netty

I have a client & server pipelines with SslHandler on both of them. It states in [docs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.html), that

> The handshake will be automatically issued for you once the Channel is
> active and SSLEngine.getUseClientMode() returns true

Since handshake involves some message exchanging, I'm wondering if other ChannelHandler's on server side (let's say decoder, logger) get these messages as well? It seems like it doesn't make sense as a handshake is something should happen only between client SslHandler and server SslHandler (physically multi-message but logically atomic thing). I guess SslHandler don't propagate handshake messages to other handlers simply by not calling `fireReadEvent` until handshake *"ping-pong"* is done but not sure about that after looking into the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All handlers "before" the `SslHandler` will see these packets. All handlers "after" the `SslHandler` will only see packets after the handshake is done (and all these packets will be decrypted).